# why isn't iMovie letting me save my video?

Tags: imovie

My sister and I have a YouTube channel, and I edited a video and wanted to save the video to my camera roll. However, I deleted it from my camera roll & my recently deleted. Now I want to save it to my camera roll but iMovie won't even let me play it because it says that I'm missing files. Is there anyway I can recover these?

[image: iMovie Screenshot]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Different! I see that you're having a problem with iMovie... did you delete the video files that went in to the movie? (i.e. the videos that you added together)

Comment: Yes I did!! Is there anyway I can get them back?

Comment: Do you have a backup of your iPhone from _before_ you deleted the files?

Comment: uhm.. How can I check that?